# Symfony и большое количество баз данных

Tags: php, symfony2

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть куча однотипных баз данных(~15-20).
Каждая связана с своим субдоменом.
Нужно сделать возможность у symfony подключаться к конкретной БД, в зависимости того с какого субдомена пришёл запрос.
Вариант с несколькими Entity Manager не подходит, т.к. баз уже много и возможно будет ещё больше.
У кого-нибудь есть адекватные варианты решения такой проблемы?
P.s. с симфони опыта пока мало. Буду рад адекватной статье по этой теме.

**UPDATE**
Был вариант предложенный знакомым:
Каждому субдоену через конфиг апача назначаем переменую окружения с именем БД.
В входном скрипте в AppKernel добавляем название содержимое этой переменой:

```
$kernel->setParametersName(getenv('DB_NAME') ? : null);
```

В AppKernel реализуем registerContainerConfiguration()

```
public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    if ($this->parametersName) {
        $loader->load(__DIR__ . '/config/parameters.d/' . $this->parametersName . '.yml');
    }
    $loader->load(__DIR__ . '/config/config_' . $this->getEnvironment() . '.yml');
}
```

Основной конфиг выглядит примерно так:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
```

Так выглядит parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: nonexists_db 
    database_user: user
    database_password: password
```

В папке /config/parameters.d/ лежат конфиги для каждой базы.
Например такой bd_first.yml

```
parameters:
    database_name: bd_first
```

Затея не удалась, т.к. бд nonexists_db  не переназначется на нужную бд.
Буду рад толковой статье по теме или подсказке, как этого квазимодо реанимировать.

Answer (score 2):

Задачу помог решить другой знакомый:
в registerContainerConfiguration конфиги надо было подключать в обратном порядке.

**UPDATE**
Справедливости ради, надо сказать, что есть [кошерный подход](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html) без велосипеда.
Однако в любом из этих случаем имя базы, к кторой обратятся первой, сохранится как дефолтное в кэше.